# Coffeescript converting function to class

Tags: class, coffeescript

How can I port this function to using the coffeescript class syntax?

```
App.PurchaseOrder = (uid) ->
  binder = new App.DataBinder(uid, "purchase-order")

  # Abstract all this out
  purchase_order =
    attributes: {}

    # The attribute setter publish changes using the DataBinder PubSub
    set: (attr_name, val) ->
      @attributes[attr_name] = val
      binder.trigger uid + ":change", [
        attr_name
        val
        this
      ]
      return

    get: (attr_name) ->
      @attributes[attr_name]

    _binder: binder

  # Subscribe to the PubSub
  binder.on uid + ":change", (evt, attr_name, new_val, initiator) ->
    purchase_order.set attr_name, new_val  if initiator isnt purchase_order
    return

  purchase_order
```

Something along the lines of this however this will not work because @attributes is not defined in the binder.on in the constructor.

```
class App.PurchaseOrder
  constructor: (@id) ->
    @binder = new App.DataBinder(@id, "purchase-order")
    @attributes = {}

    # Subscribe to the PubSub
    @binder.on @id + ":change", (evt, attr_name, new_val, initiator) ->
      @attributes.set attr_name, new_val  if initiator isnt @attributes
      return

  # The attribute setter publish changes using the DataBinder PubSub
  set: (attr_name, val) ->
    @attributes[attr_name] = val
    @binder.trigger @id + ":change", [
      attr_name
      val
      this
    ]
    return

  get: (attr_name) ->
    @attributes[attr_name]
```

Comment: Just curious - what is the goal here. The question is a little outside the scope of 'your' question, but I'm curious - for learning purposes - what you are doing here.

Comment: I have a rails app that I am trying to augment the ruby classes with js classes without the use of a client side framework.  In this case I am setting up a convention that a client side purchase order model will be automatically bound to html elements that have specific data attributes.  So if I have a page that has `<td data-id="1" data-class="PurchaseOrder" data-attr="state">new</td>` and I do `purchase_order = new App.PurchaseOrder(1)` then `purchase_order.set("state", "pending")` the html element will be updated.

Comment: It is a WIP but you can check out the source code here: https://github.com/mfpiccolo/happy_place_demo. and the demo here: http://happy-place-demo.herokuapp.com/purchase_orders. By entering the id in the input field you can edit the table directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do something like this

```
@binder.on @id + ":change", (evt, attr_name, new_val, initiator) ->
  @attributes.set attr_name, new_val  if initiator isnt @attributes
  return
```

then it means that this function will be invoked in global context or in the context of e.g. event object, but the point is that `this` may not point to the object you want. Instead of `->` use `=>`

```
@binder.on @id + ":change", (evt, attr_name, new_val, initiator) =>
  @attributes.set attr_name, new_val  if initiator isnt @attributes
  return
```

then `this` inside the callback will be bound statically, in this example to the instance of your class.

Comment: Small correction: I think the context of `this` in the event handler will be the event itself, not the global context.

Comment: @JedSchneider well, you may be right, all depends on how the callback is called. Updated the answer to be more precise on this.

Comment: The => is what I was looking for.  Thank you.  Do you think you could change the `@attributes` to `this` because I actually wanted to call `set` on the purchase order instance not the attributes object.

Comment: @mpiccolo Yes, you can use `@set` instead of `@attributes.set` here, if that's what you want.

Answer (score 0):

how about this:

```
# Subscribe to the PubSub
@binder.on @id + ":change", ((evt, attr_name, new_val, initiator) -> 
    @attributes.set attr_name, new_val  if initiator isnt @attributes ).bind @
return
```